# File Safe password recovery in honor 9n

Tags: password

I want to recover honor file safe password. And I forgot the password & security questions... How to recover the password & my files. Any instructions from here?

Answer (score 0):

if you forgot the password and security question of your device then you may change your password through Huawei ID. When you try to try to put the password there you get an option of Forgot password>> another verification method>> Huawei Id.

If you forgot your Huawei ID and password, then you have to reset your device with the proper backup of the device data :(